# React, Mocking API

Tags: reactjs, json, api, mocking

For this project I must not use a react library. I would like to be able to acces the data via a local JSON file (db.json for example) if I don't have access to the API (but retrieve the data from the API if I have access to it). How can I do this?

I make a useFecth :

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

export function useFetch(url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})
    const [isLoading, setLoading] = useState(true)
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (!url) return
      setLoading(true)
      async function fetchData() {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(url)
          const data = await response.json()
          setData(data)
        } catch (err) {
          console.log(err)
          setError(true)
        } finally {
          setLoading(false)
        }
      }
      fetchData()
    }, [url])
    return { isLoading, data, error }
  }
```

and I display datas in different pages :

```
import { useFetch } from "../../utils/hooks";
import logements from "../../__mock__/db.json"

function Logement() {
  const { logementId } = useParams();

  const {
    data: logement,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/logements/${logementId}`);

  if (isLoading) return <h1>LOADING...</h1>;

  if (error) {
    return <Error />;
  }

  return (
    <div className="logements">
      <Slider slides={logement.pictures} />
      <div className="content">
        <div className="informations">
          <h1>{logement.title}</h1>
          <p>{logement.location}</p>
          <div className="tags__wrapper">
            {logement.tags.map((tag, index) => (
              <Tags key={index} getTag={tag} />
            ))}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="rating__host">
          <Rating rating={logement.rating} />
          <Host host={logement.host} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="collapsible">
        <Accordion title="Description" content={logement.description} />
        <Accordion title="Equipement" content={logement.equipments} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Logement;
```

```
import { useFetch } from "../../utils/hooks";
import logements from "../../__mock__/db.json"

function Home() {
  const {
    data: logementList,
    isLoading,
    error,
  } = useFetch(`http://localhost:8000/api/logements`);

  if (isLoading) return <h1>LOADING...</h1>;

  if (error) {
    return <Error />;
  }

  console.log(logementList);

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      <Banner image={image} title={Slogan} className="banner" />
      <HomeWrap>
        <Logements>
          {logementList.map((logement) => {
            console.log(logement._id);
            return (
              <CardWrapper key={logement.id}>
                <Link to={`/logement/${logement._id}`}>
                  <Card cover={logement.cover} title={logement.title} />
                </Link>
              </CardWrapper>
            );
          })}
        </Logements>
      </HomeWrap>
    </Wrapper>
  );
}

export default Home;
```

Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create node server and add your all json there or use
google firebase to handle response if api is not available through url.

In promise then check if correct status is available in api otherwise call node server.

Comment: This is what I did, but I must have a local json file, and I would like to know if it's possible to retrieve data to this file when I don't have access to the API.